# Setting up structured data for products without a price

Tags: structured-data

I am trying to add structured data from schema.org to my e-commerce site, but I do not show price since the majority of our products need to quoted. Is it possible to add the price as request a quote or do search engines frown upon this?

Answer (score 4):

It's not really possible to display a price as "request a quote", Egregory, and Google may look at that type of price markup as spammy.  I'm not sure how other search engines would accept that type of markup, either.  Your best option would be to leave the price out of the markup.

David

Comment: Would the markup still show? I get errors within webmaster tools saying that I need to add price.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the product rich snippet would not be displayed, Egregory.  Google's guidelines state that for a product rich snippet, the product name, info, price and price currency must be marked up.  So from a structured data standpoint, leaving the price out of the markup would be fine.  But from Google's standpoint, they will not give it a rich snippet.

Comment: Weak, cool thanks for the information. I did see they allow for Extending the markup so I might try that out and see how it goes.