# What is the priceRange parameter for Google Structured Data Reviews?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets, price

I am trying to determine what are the acceptable values for the `priceRange` parameter. On Google I see "$$$" and that's it.

Can someone explain if I should be using `$$$` literally or a decimal amount.

Comment: Related: [What is the meaning of the priceRange property in Schema.org?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40790269/1591669)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems there is no "standard" for this, and probably is born out of the rating system for Restaurants.

It seems the convention is:

> - $ = Inexpensive, usually $10 and under
> - $$ = Moderately expensive, usually between $10-$25
> - $$$ = Expensive, usually between $25-$45
> - $$$$ = Very Expensive, usually $50 and up
>
> [Source](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100623180706AAnObPJ)

It seems TripAdvisor use the local currency symbol as the indicator:

> As a reviewer in Korean, you will fill in according to Won ₩, in Greek it will be according to Euros €. Aussies, on the .com.au version of the website get just $ signs, so rather subtle there. The understanding would be AUD$.
>
> [Source](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g1-i12104-k7052014-What_should_the_Dollar_igns_mean_in_the_restaurant_reviews-Help_us_make_TripAdvisor_better.html#54767518)

But a user has quite rightly pointed out on the official schema.org Github that `priceRange` is ambiguous.

> The property schema.org/priceRange is ambiguous because it specifies text for a currency range...
>
> [Source](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1307)

---

### TL;DR

> Use the `price` property with a range modeled as a `PriceSpecification`
> http://schema.org/price
>
> Source - [Github Issue](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1307)

Answer (score 4):

The `priceRange` property seems pretty meaningless, as Shannon points out.

But Google has (within the last few days, as far as I'm aware) started recommending it for all `localBusiness` structured data, triggering warnings in the [structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/). So, I expect many businesses to suddenly start expressing their pricing in arbitrary strings of `$$$`, especially [those for whom an explicit price list isn't appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879318/setting-up-structured-data-for-products-without-a-price), e.g. where prices can only be quoted upon request.

It seems that the issue is creating some confusion on the Google product forum, with new `image` [errors](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/MaYg34BGH7I) and `address` warnings have started appearing alongside the `priceRange` [warnings](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/rHfrihaNiow/70v2WwIkCAAJ). It's possible that Google has unintentionally started treating all businesses as restaurants and will backtrack, but I'm only speculating.

(The question is about reviews, rather than `localBusiness` data, so this may not be directly relevant to the OP. It's hopefully of interest to others finding this thread first—as I did—after seeing `priceRange` warnings in the structured data testing tool. I considered entering this as a comment under Shannon's answer, but didn't have enough reputation points...)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that because they used a symbol ranging from $ / $$ / $$$, that it means that its a relative and not fixed value system.

So to the general consumer, they would interpret $ meaning cheap, $$ being average and $$$ meaning expensive. I personally could not assume a value as three dollar symbols ($$$) could mean two different amounts between two different types of businesses.

For example: a hotel could say $$$, a burger joint could say $$$ and a car dealership could say $$$. In a relative system, this would work as they could all be expensive. On a fixed value system, it wouldn't work and a business such as the car dealership would have to define the value as $$$$$$ for instance but this would just start to look ridiculous to the average person; I mean if it were a boat/airplane manufacturing business, it could be $$$$$$$$$$$$ excluding currency conversion. Fixed value system feels too complicated for an example of "$$$". I would expect an example like "$100-$300 or $25M-$50M" for that type of system.

I do like Richard Wallis's scale in this thread though (https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1307):

```
$ = inexpensive
$$ = moderate
$$$ = expensive
$$$$ = very expensive
$$$$$ = if you have to ask the price, you can't afford it*
* Apparently attributed to J. P. Morgan, although disputed
```