# What is the meaning of the priceRange property in Schema.org?

Tags: schema.org, price

What does the property **priceRange** mean in Schema.org?

https://schema.org/priceRange

I don't understand what is mean that, I live in Kazakhstan, maybe my culture or language does not give clear. Can you give me example for Kazakhstan country, where we use tenge currency.

Comment: You say hCard, but the `priceRange` property from Schema.org has nothing to do with hCard (which is from Microformats).

Comment: @unor yes you are right, but why when I use [link]https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=http%3A%2F%2Fpot.kz%2FON-Pro-Complex-Gainer-4450-gram[/link]

Comment: @unor I edited my first post

Comment: I see, interesting. But now your question is about something else, and my answer doesn’t make much sense :) Do you mind making this question about Schema.org, and maybe create another question about hCard? Note the difference in case (`pricerange` vs. `priceRange`), so I guess the Structured Data Testing Tool is not refering to the Schema.org property (or it’s just bugged).

Comment: As you accepted my answer, I edited your question. Feel free to create another one about the hCard issue with Google’s SDTT. Your previous revision (e.g. for link to the image) is here: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40790269/2

Comment: Related: [What is the priceRange parameter for Google Structured Data Reviews?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40005100/1591669)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Schema.org property `priceRange`](http://schema.org/priceRange) gives the range of approximate prices of the products/services typically offered by that `LocalBusiness`.

There seem to be two formats used in examples:

- Specify as many currency symbols as there are digits in the price. So for prices from 100 to 999, you would use `₸₸₸`; for prices from 10 to 99, you would use `₸₸` etc.

  (used in [example 4 on `LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness))
- Specify the actual range, e.g. for prices from 90 to 240, then you would use `90 ₸ - 240 ₸` etc.

  (used in [example 1 on `Hotel`](http://schema.org/Hotel#example-1))

In the issue [priceRange property is ambiguous](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1307), this property gets discussed (it *might* get deprecated in the future, or at least defined more clearly, but we’ll have to see).

Comment: why it uses in hCard? :)